FRN where is the duration risk
If I take a floating rate note that pays compounded 3months sofr, I don't see why there is still IR risk.
Let's say my floating rate bond has a maturity of 1year and pays quaterly. So it's going to pay on April the compounded sofr during January, February, March. Since SOFR is overnight I don't know what my coupon payement will be in January, but I will know it on April and receive the coupon at that date.
Then why do I have risk during January, February and March? If sofr goes up or down during that period will be reflected in my coupon but since we discount by compounded SOFR the up/down effects cancel out. (if sofr goes down coupon is lower but discount factor is lower...). Basically we get the coupon $\prod_{d} (1+SOFR_d) - 1$ where $d$ spans accross the dates in January, February, March.
Hence I don't get where is my IR risk here?
Apparently the IR risk is in between the coupon but I don't get why. For me the problem comes from what has been realized. The second coupon is going to be discounted by the compounded SOFR on January, February, March times the compounded SOFR on April, May, June. Since for the second coupon I get the compounded on April, May, June, I guess the problem comes from the compounded on January, February, March since I am going to discount by that?

In practice, credit-risky floaters pay infex + fixed spread (sometimes also index x gearing). Almost all the interest rate sensitivity comes from the fixed spread.

@DimitriVulis Thank you for your comment. But then if there's a spread added, it's the same as adding a fixed coupon bond no? With coupon equal to the spread. But then in that case the rate risk doesn't only happen between the coupon?

(1) You are receiving coupons with a delay, you get in April an interest rate that is measured in Jan-Feb-Mar, so you have interest rate risk, though the duration is small ( a few months)  (2) The previous reasoning neglects the fixed spread,  which is an annuity of N remaining payments. That also has interest rate risk, which Mr. Vulis says is bigger than the "delayed coupons" effect mentioned in (1).

Pls can you add further clarity to the coupon payment. Is it daily SOFR, compounded daily and paid quarterly ?

@nbbo2 I think the problem is that he is using SOFR as discount factor so there's no IR risk since you get compounded SOFR and discount by compounded SOFR. I guess to have the IR risk you need to discount using OIS or ZC curve
